# c# how to compare and replace into a list<class> from another

Tags: c#, linq, class

I have little problem checking and storing new data from an old one. I have a class structured like this :

```
public class class1
{
    public List<Class2> class2List {get,set}
    ...
}
public class class2
    {
        public Class3 class3 {get,set}
        ...
    }
public class class3
    {
        public string name {get,set}
        public int index {get,set}
        ...
    }
```

I want to create a method that will take a class 2 input and check if indexes are the same as old class1, if yes i want to store it. I try to do sme linQ to solve my problem but I am not an expert and I am a little stuck...

```
public static void SaveNewDataOnlyIfSameIndex(class1 workingData, List<class2> newdata)
    {
        List<class3> LocalWorkingDataClass3 = new List<class3>();
        foreach(class2 item in workingData.class2)
            {
                LocalWorkingDataClass3.add(item.class3);
            }
        List<int> LocalWorkingDataIndex = new List<int>();
        foreach(class3 item2 in LocalWorkingDataClass3 )
            {
                LocalWorkingDataIndex.add(item2.index);
            }
        List<class3> LocalEqualClasstoReplace = new List<class3>();
        LocalEqualClasstoReplace = newdata.Where(File => LocalWorkingDataIndex.Equals(File.Index));
    }
```

Comment: You do nto need for loops.  You can use AddRange() : LocalWorkingDataClass3.addrange(workingData)

Comment: A readability consideration: in C# class names are PascalCase and local variables are camelCase.

Comment: When you say 'the indexes are the same' do you mean every index matches? Or there is at least one matching index?

Comment: i wanted to say if the index properties are equal. Not the index of array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can't understand very well what you need, but you can try to do something like this, using Linq:

```
public static void SaveNewDataOnlyIfSameIndex(Class1 WorkingData, List<Class2> Newdata)
{
    List<int> LocalWorkingDataClass3Index = WorkingData.Class2List.Select(i => i.Class3.Index).ToList()
 
    List<Class3> LocalEqualClasstoReplace = new List<Class3>();
    LocalEqualClasstoReplace = newdata.Where(f => LocalWorkingDataClass3Index.Contains(f.Class3.Index));
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what i need, i want to test if the value the value of all Index in my WorkingData.Class2List[x].class3.index are equals to my Newdata[x] class3.index.

If it's true, my new data will replace my working data. (all the classe3 not only the index)

But just a question: LocalEqualClasstoReplace = newdata.Where(f => LocalWorkingDataClass3Index.Contains(f.Class3.Index));

in this line, the contains can make a difference of index = 1 and index = 10 ?
Because if he test if 10 contains 1 this will be true.

Comment: Index is an integer value, so, in this case, the "contains" control is referred to an array of integer, not to a string.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi.
> First of all, I am not sure that i got your question.

```
    public class Class1
    {
        public List<Class2> class2List {get;set;}
    }
    public class Class2
    {
       public string name {get;set;}
       public int index {get;set;}
    }

    public void CompareAndReplace(ref Class1 orginalDataList, Class2 newData){
       var check=orginalDataList.class2List.FirstOrDefault(g=>g.index==newData.index);
       if(check!=null){
         check.name=newData.name;
       }
    }

   //example to use assuming to "orginalDataList" has some datas..
   
    CompareAndReplace(ref orginalDataList,new Class2{index=1,name="Hello"});
```